# Close Modal issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following code to open my Modal.

The modal opens as expected - and appends `open` to the parent class. However, when 'close' is clicked, it doesn't close & `close` is not added to the class.

Can someone explain why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $window = $(window)

    $(".modal-trigger").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        var id = $(e.target).attr("href")

        $(id).addClass("open")

        $(id).find('.close').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $(e.target).parent().removeClass(".open")
        });

    })

});

</script>
```

My `Close` button **HTML**:
`<button class="close icon-close"></button>`

Comment: reading the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/): `.removeClass('open')` ... no need for the dot

Comment: where did your **semicolons** go?

Comment: Even removing the `.` doesn't fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `parent()` brings you to correct level. Instead try to remove `.open` class from the element you add this class in the first place, i.e. `$(id)`:

```
$(".modal-trigger").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(e.target).attr("href");
    $(id).addClass("open");

    $(id).find('.close').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(id).removeClass("open");
        $(this).off();
    });
});
```

Also you probably want to unbind click event from close button, otherwise it will bind multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. No errors in my console either.

Comment: Works perfectly now - fantastic! Please accept this green tick and a virtual hug* from me :-) *optional